# How to connect to MySQL server using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Visual Studio 2019 community edition. I want to connect to MySQL using **Entity Framework core**. I do not want to use Entity Framework 6.

I am running into following issues:

1. I created a new project using "ASP .NET CORE App and ASP .NET CORE Web App" template and it does not show option to add Entity Framework.

[image]

2. If I use tools > Connect to Database option from menu, I do not see option to connect to MySQL. How can I enable this option.

[image]

Comment: perhaps you need to install mysql for visual studio for it to appear there.

Answer (score 5):

Step by Step - **Database First**

**First install these packages**

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

**So on Powershell go to project folder [right click on project and select open in terminal (visual studio)]**

[image]

Now, you can run this command

[image]

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Servel=localhost;Database=tempSQLonNetCore;user=root;password=;" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql"

### **If your connection is true, your DbContext Generated and entities adding to your project.**

**Now you must inject DbContext, Described in the Codefirst section**

---

Step by Step - **Code First**

**First install these packages**

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
3. Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

**Add connection string look like in appsetting.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings" : {
    "DefaultConnection" : "Servel=localhost;Database=tempSQLonNetCore;user=root;password=;"
}
```

**Now, Create your DB context **

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    // Your Entities
}
```

**finally configure the app for connecting**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
     options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});
```

> Now you can use Migration if you need to create or update your database [Migration](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20use%20code-based%20migration%2C%20you%20need,with%20the%20Up%20%28%29%20and%20Down%20%28%29%20methods.)

Answer (score 3):

Install "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019.

Then follow the instructions to configure it in your project: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/#getting-started

Disclaimer: I have made a small number of contributions to the Pomelo package.

Comment: I will not propose official package also. It do not supports async operations and just emulates them.

Answer (score 0):

EFCore is a package, not a file you would add to your project. Go to Project>NuGet Package Manager and install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. Then you can scaffold the connection to your database by running the `scaffold-dbcontext` command in the PM console.

Comment: Or, as a less headache way of scaffolding, install the EF Core Power Tools VS extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools

Answer (score 0):

did you try installing through the console?

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 5.0.11

make sure that this source is added to your nuget sources in VS
**https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json**